# What it means "all objects that could be named in the language to have equal status in python"

Tags: python

I am learning OOP in python and following [this tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_object_oriented_programming.php) I am having hard time to understanding what Rossum said

> "One of my goals for Python was to make it so that all objects were "first class." By this, I meant that I wanted all objects that could be named in the language (e.g., integers, strings, functions, classes, modules, methods, and so on) to have equal status."

I have two question :

What is "first class in python"?

What it means by equal status?

Answer (score 0):

I think the next sentence clears it up:

> "That is, they can be assigned to variables, placed in lists, stored
>   in dictionaries, passed as arguments, and so forth"

The thing that makes python easy to learn is that you don't (usually) have to fiddle around with things like typecasting.  Objects are quickly and intuitively constructed.  Your lack of understanding, I believe stems from the fact that you probably haven't studied other languages that have weird nuances about how different types of variables interact.  in C, for example 5/10= 0, but python will automatically convert that to floating point division

Comment: You're right, the next sentence clears it up.  But your explanatory paragraph veers off into the irrelevant.  This has nothing to do with typecasting.  A better example is that you can easily pass functions as arguments to other functions. In C you would have to use pointers.  In Ruby you would have to decorate it specially so it could be passed and then inside the function you would have to call it with a different than the usual calling methods.